# How to call JFrame from JSP?

Tags: java, swing, jsp, applet, jframe

I wanna know that how to call JFrame from jsp.
When I click button on the browser, I want to call frame. 
But I do not know how to do.
If you don't mine, please explain me.

Here is some code!

```
package testing;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class LoadFile extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

    private JPanel jContentPane = null;
    private JList listCertificate = null;
    private JLabel jLabel = null;
    private JPasswordField password = null;
    private JButton btnLoad = null;
    private JLabel jLabel1 = null;

    /**
     * This is the xxx default constructor
     */
    public LoadFile() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes this
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public void init() {
        this.setSize(400, 306);
        this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jContentPane
     * 
     * @return javax.swing.JPanel
     */
    private JPanel getJContentPane() {
        if (jContentPane == null) {
            jLabel1 = new JLabel();
            jLabel1.setBounds(new Rectangle(28, 19, 296, 30));
            jLabel1.setText("Choose your certificate");
            jLabel = new JLabel();
            jLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(54, 228, 88, 26));
            jLabel.setText("Password");
            jContentPane = new JPanel();
            jContentPane.setLayout(null);
            jContentPane.add(getListCertificate(), null);
            jContentPane.add(jLabel, null);
            jContentPane.add(getPassword(), null);
            jContentPane.add(getBtnLoad(), null);
            jContentPane.add(jLabel1, null);
        }
        return jContentPane;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes listCertificate  
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JList    
     */
    private JList getListCertificate() {
        if (listCertificate == null) {
            listCertificate = new JList();
            listCertificate.setBounds(new Rectangle(26, 56, 345, 149));
            Vector<String> alias = getAlias();
            listCertificate.setListData(alias);
        }
        return listCertificate;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes password 
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JPasswordField   
     */
    private JPasswordField getPassword() {
        if (password == null) {
            password = new JPasswordField();
            password.setBounds(new Rectangle(152, 224, 171, 28));
        }
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes btnLoad  
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JButton  
     */
    private JButton getBtnLoad() {
        if (btnLoad == null) {
            btnLoad = new JButton();
            btnLoad.setBounds(new Rectangle(189, 261, 70, 30));
            btnLoad.setText("Load");
            btnLoad.addActionListener(this);
        }
        return btnLoad;
    }


    public Vector<String> getAlias(){
        Vector<String> str = new Vector<String>();
        KeyStore ks;
        try {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
            ks.load(null, null);
            Enumeration en = ks.aliases();
            String aliasName = "";
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
                aliasName = (String) en.nextElement();
                str.add(aliasName);
            }

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object obj = arg0.getSource();
        if(obj == btnLoad){
            String alias = (String)getListCertificate().getSelectedValue();
            String password = getPassword().getText();

        }
    }

}  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="294,19"
```

I want to call that class from JSP.
Thanks.

Comment: JFrame doesn't extend Applet.

Comment: No, I extends Applet and I used JFrame at this class.

public **class LoadFromStore extends Applet** implements ActionListener{

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 **private JFrame frame = null;**  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="369,9"
 private JPanel contentPane = null;
 private JList lstCertificate = null;
 private JLabel jLabel = null;
 private JPasswordField password = null;
 private JButton btnLoad = null;
 private JLabel jLabel1 = null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I click button on the browser, I want to call frame.

Launch the frame directly from an HTML link (or button) using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).